# How can I timeout my Python async function after 10 minutes?

Tags: python, discord, timeout, task

I have an `async master_loop` function that loops every 30 minutes. In this function, I call `scrape_message = await scrape()`. The issue is that `scrape()` gets stuck quite often and I would like to add something to quit `scrape()` after 10 minutes. Just abandon everything and delete all local variables that it uses. I've been trying to figure out how to do that but all the examples online use `asyncio` to do their looping but I use `tasks.loop` imported from `discord.ext`. Does anyone know how to timeout my function?

```
# big daddy loop that runs every fifteen minutes
@tasks.loop(time=times)
async def master_loop(client, mongo_client):
    print('loop engaged...')

    correct_channel = client.get_channel(channel_number)

    # start the curate function
    await curate(correct_channel, mongo_client)

    # start the scrape function (THIS IS THE FUNCTION I WANT TO CANCEL AFTER 10 MINUTES!!!)
    scrape_message = await scrape(correct_channel, mongo_client)

    log = client.get_channel(1141886539157221457)
    await log.send(scrape_message)

    print('done')
```

Comment: [`asyncio.timeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.timeout)